# Сортировка image <Binary data>

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

```
     protected void BindGridView()
     {

         if (ViewState["poisk"] != null)
         {
             Label7.Text = (string)ViewState["poisk"];
             string querrysearch = (string)ViewState["poisk"];
             DataTable dt = new DataTable();

             string find = "SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE(Name like '%' + @name + '%' or Autor like '%' + @autor + '%' or Editor like '%' + @editor + '%' or Year like '%' + @year + '%' or About like '%' + @about + '%' or Type like '%' + @type + '%')";
             SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(find, con);

             comm.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
             comm.Parameters.Add("@autor", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
             comm.Parameters.Add("@editor", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
             comm.Parameters.Add("@year", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
             comm.Parameters.Add("@about", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
             comm.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;

             con.Open();
             comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
             SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
             da.SelectCommand = comm;
             DataSet ds = new DataSet();

             da.Fill(dt);
             con.Close();

             if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
             {
                 GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                 GridView1.DataBind();
                 ViewState["dt"] = dt;
                 ViewState["sort"] = "Asc";
             }
         }
         else
         {
             Label7.Text = "Cheto kak-to nikak";
             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
             SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from catalog", con);
             con.Open();
             da.Fill(dt);
             con.Close();

             if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
             {
                 GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                 GridView1.DataBind();
                 ViewState["dt"] = dt;
                 ViewState["sort"] = "Asc";
             }
         }


     }
```

**Аннотация:**
Вот код. Он отлично работает(desc правда не сортирует, но тут это не важно сейчас). В готовой таблице так же есть поле picture, которому соответствует поле c datatype image в mssql. Сортировка работает по **всем** полям.

**Вопрос:** 
Какая логика сортировки поля picture? (Напоминаю, что оно состоит только с image).

Comment: Мой вариант ответа: binary data сортируется как string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Или вообще запретить сортировку по Image, или по клику на нее сортировать по ID. Или по имени картинки. Или по чему угодно.

Если пользователь скажет "сортирует неправильно" - узнать у него, как правильно и переделать.

Comment: Не-не, не в том как нужно сделать чтобы работало вопрос, а в том как оно работает сейчас. Мне именно с теоретической точки зрения интересно, а в мануалах не нашел.

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron с теоретической точки зрения - при загрузке картинки в базу нужно открывать ее, извлекать какую-то метрику (размер, количество пикселей, яркость, "зеленость"). сохранять метрику в базу. и при сортировке "по картинке" сортировать по этой метрике.

Comment: Вот, нужно. Но мы этого ничего не делаем, но по какому-то критерию оно все-таки сортируется. Так вот вопрос: как оно работает СЕЙЧАС?

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron а, дошло. надо копать исходники.

Comment: именно какую часть? функции что я привел или самого .нет ядра или чего?

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron это asp.net. картинка рендерится не напрямую. вместо нее на страницу кидатеся `<img src="...." />`. у вас эта колонка скорее всего выглядит как TemplateField на странице. и у него прописан [`SortExpression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagridcolumn.sortexpression(v=vs.110).aspx) - вот по нему и сортируется.

Comment: Ага, <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="picture" SortExpression="picture">

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30341/discussion-between-disguiseperceptron-and-pashapash).

Answer (score 1):

> Server: Msg 306, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The text, ntext, and image
>   data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or
>   LIKE operator.

потому что нельзя сортировать поля типа image. кстати, этот тип поля уже давно не используется, переходите на binary/varbinary

Comment: Пользователь кликает по контролу сортировки поля, происходит некоторое действие и порядок выдачи строк меняется. Как называется этот процесс, если мы выяснили что это не сортировка? Какая логика работы этого процесса? Другими словами всегда ли он работает именно так? Что мы можем сделать с кодом не затрагивая БД чтобы повлиять на него?